# Python Pandas: Bar plot X axis issue

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I got this dataframe df,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

table = {'Count_Product': pd.Series([1,2,3]), 'Count_Transaction': pd.Series([1,1,2])}
df = pd.DataFrame(table)
df

Count_Product   Count_Transaction
0   1   1
1   2   1
2   3   2
```

And I want to do a simple bar plot where the x axis is Count_Product and y axis is Count_Transaction.  I used the following code to generate,

```
%matplotlib inline

ax = df['Count_Product'].plot(kind='bar', figsize=(5,5), color='blue')
ax.set_ylabel("Count_Transaction")
ax.set_xlabel("Count_Product")
patches, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(patches, labels, loc='best')
```

And the graph output is,

[image]

My problem is the x-axis is showing 0,1,2 instead of 1,2,3 from the Count_Product column.  It looks like it is taking the 1st column as the x-axis automatically.

Does anyone know how can I code the correct column to use the Count_Product column as the x-axis?

Thanks,
Lobbie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need first [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) from column `Count_Product` and then change `df['Count_Product'].plot` to `df['Count_Transaction'].plot`:

```
df = df.set_index('Count_Product')

ax = df['Count_Transaction'].plot(kind='bar', figsize=(5,5), color='blue')
ax.set_ylabel("Count_Transaction")
ax.set_xlabel("Count_Product")
patches, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(patches, labels, loc='best')
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Hi Jezrael, thank you so much!  I was thinking about I need to set an index somewhere and you showed me.  Thanks again, Lobbie.

Comment: Yes, I also need to "change df['Count_Product'].plot to df['Count_Transaction'].plot".  I also notice I do not need to do df['Count_Transaction'] and just use df.plot will also work.  Thanks again.